# Change text in tree node in a TCL ttk:treeview

Tags: treeview, tcl, tk-toolkit, ttk

I have added a ttk::treeview in my TCL/Tk application.During the first initialization I set a treenode's value to "Inactive".

```
 set parent [$nb.props.tree insert {} 2 -id traffic -text "Traffic" -open true]        
 $nb.props.tree insert $parent end -text "Status" -values "Inactive"
 $nb.props.tree insert $parent end -text "Location" -values $Path
```

There are also a lot of other nodes. But later only the value of '**Status**' may change. Now the problem is I don't want to delete and repopulate the whole tree because that that is causing flickering.I just want to change the value of the Status node. But I am not sure how to **select the node** and **only change its value** later . please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual page (http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm) says:

> *pathname insert* returns the item identifier of the newly created item. [...]

And:

> *pathname item* item ?-option ?value -option value...?
>       Query or modify the options for the specified item. [...]

Comment: Ok. But for this I have to store the generated Item Identifier. can this be avoided by some fixed and known id?
like .tree.traffic.status  is this kind of selection possible by some mean like -id parameter ?

Comment: I think not.  The identifiers must be unique, so the user supplied text cannot be used to create item identifiers.  Nor is there any method for the user to supply an item identifier.

Comment: I found the solution. We can use user supplied id indeed. 

The manual page (http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm) says:

pathname insert parent index ?-id id? options...
**If -id is specified, it is used as the item identifier; id must not already exist in the tree. Otherwise, a new unique identifier is generated**